# Auto-complete decorator in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm learning Swing and trying to make a text editor with autocomplete as an exercise. I use Netbeans.

When I create JFrame and add a text area to it I end up with such auto-generated code:

```
package javaapplication5;
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

What I want to try is apply Autocomplete decorator described at

```
http://www.jdocs.com/swingx/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/AutoCompleteDecorator.html
```

When I try to do

```
List list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jTextArea1, list);
```

it results into:

```
error: <identifier> expected
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jTextArea1, list);
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching in google for [AutoCompleteDecorator api](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/AutoCompleteDecorator.html) there is no method with your signature. You have to pass a boolean as an argument if it's `strictMatching`.

```
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jTextArea1, list,true);
```

Comment: `error: <identifier> expected
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jTextArea1, list, true);
error: <identifier> expected
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jTextArea1, list, true);
error: <identifier> expected
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jTextArea1, list, true);
error: illegal start of type
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jTextArea1, list, true);`

Comment: @ror6ax did you download the library? and clean&build

Comment: @ror6ax `swingx` is a third-party library you have to download it, and add it to your project. Here you can download [link](https://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/) `swingx-all-1.6.4.jar` there you have everything